# How to Count Times an ID Appears in a Column in a Different Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

Apologies in advance: I'm sure this is relatively easy and has been asked ad nauseam, but I just can't quite come up with the proper search.

Basically, I'm trying to take a list of IDs queryed from one table, and then see which ones DO NOT appear in a separate column in another table.

It's a Wordpress MySQL database. Authors are attached to a Post via metadata. Both authors and posts are considered to be posts for database purposes. There is one table containing both posts/authors: `wp_posts`/`wp`. There is another table containing the metadata attached to a post/author: `wp_postmeta`/`wm`.

I'm attempting to take a list of authors from `wp_posts` and see which ones are orphans, i.e. not attached to a post, by checking a column called `meta_value` in `wp_postmeta`.

An Author is tied to a Post by having the Author's ID from `wp_posts` show up in the `wm.meta_value` column for a Post. But Authors themselves are declared by having an `'author'` value in the same column. So an Author with an ID of `17078` will have an `'author'` value in `wm.meta_value`, while a Post attributed to that Author will have `17078` in `wm.meta_value`.

The following query gets me about halfway there by returning all the Authors that we have in our database:

```
    SELECT 
        post_title,
        ID
    FROM
        wp_posts wp
    JOIN
        wp_postmeta wm
    ON
        wp.ID = wm.post_id
    WHERE
        wm.meta_value = 'author'
```

I need to somehow take that returned list and highlight which of those IDs do not show up in the `wm.meta_value` column for all the posts. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't understand what you need to find. Can you provide an example of how the records are and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need below -

```
SELECT ID
FROM wp_postmeta wm
WHERE wm.meta_value = 'author'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM wp_postmeta wm2
                WHERE wm2.ID = wm.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this ([view on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pD64HHg1gPr2BuPbqXzWW6/0)):

```sql
WITH 
authors AS (
   SELECT post_id
   FROM wp_postmeta wm
   WHERE wm.meta_value = 'author' 
),
posts AS (
   SELECT post_id, (meta_value +0) AS author_id
   FROM wp_postmeta wm
   WHERE wm.meta_value <> 'author' 
)
SELECT post_id
FROM authors
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM posts
     WHERE authors.post_id = posts.author_id 
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately our MySQL version is still stuck on 5.7

Answer (score 0):

The query that I eventually went with, thanks to the hints provided by the other answers, was:

```
  SELECT 
    wm.post_id
  FROM
    wp_postmeta wm
  WHERE
    wm.meta_value = 'author'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM wp_postmeta wm2
    WHERE wm2.meta_key = '_author'
    AND wm2.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%"',wm.post_id,'"%')
  )
```